# How to calculate short circuit current contribution of a PV plant into network?

Tags: short-circuit, solar-energy, fault

I want to calculate the short circuit current contribution of my PV plant. I have only data from the inverter manufacturer but I am not sure if I have to simply add up all the inverter's short circuit current contributions or if there is a specific method .